# Finding the azimuth of a triangle's corner (artillery problem)

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

*Apologies if the title is not up to snuff. I'm by no means experienced with math, and I did my best to word it as directly as possible. If there is a better title, please indicate it to me and I will adjust accordingly, if possible.*

This is an artillery problem I've been trying to work through my head. The source of this problem is a game, *Foxhole*. In this game, a spotter measures the azimuth & range to the gun, and the the azimuth & range to the target. With some calculation, the crew of the gun can determine the range and azimuth to the target, achieve a firing solution, and fire upon the target.

**What is known:**

- The spotter knows his azimuth to gun (48°) & distance to gun (47m)
- The spotter knows his azimuth to target (331°) & distance to target (33m)

---

**Step 1**

To find the interior angle between target, spotter & gun, I did the following:

$x = (360-331) +48$

$x = 77$

Finding that the interior angle between target, spotter & gun is 77°.

---

**Step 2**

To find the distance from the gun to the target, I used:

$x^2=a^2+b^2-2(a)(b)cos(C)$

$x^2=47^2+33^2-2(47)(33)cos(77)$

$x=50.992$

Finding that the distance from the gun to the target is approximately 51m.

---

**Step 3**

To find one of the remaining 2 angles, I used:

$\frac{sin(A)}{a}=\frac{sin(B)}{b}$

$\frac{sin(77)}{51}=\frac{sin(X)}{33}$

$x=40.29686$

Finding that the interior angle between target, gun & spotter is 40°. Since we already found that the angle between target, spotter & gun is 77°, we now know that the last angle between spotter, target & gun is 63°.

---

**The hangup:**

I'm now trying to find the azimuth from the gun to the target, however, this portion of the problem evades me. I've gotten to where I am through YouTube tutorials and my own education, but I can't work this portion of the problem out, nor do I know the proper terminology to find the process to uncover it.

Any assistance or advice would be greatly appreciated!

- [Image of my progress thusfar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGNhq.png)

Comment: You just need [alternate angles theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transversal_(geometry)#Alternate_angles) to find that X=180°+48°+40°.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to tackle this problem is to use vectors.

Let $G$ be the vector from the spotter to the gun, and $T$ be the vector from the spotter to the target, then we have:

$ G = 47 (\sin 48^\circ, \cos 48^\circ) $

$ T = 33 ( \sin 331^\circ, \cos 331^\circ) $

Then the vector extending from the gun to the target is given by $ S $, where

$S = (S_x, S_y) = T - G = s ( \sin \phi, \cos \phi ) $

To determine the azimuth $\phi$, calculate the tangent of this angle which is

$\tan \phi = \dfrac{S_x}{S_y} $

Then find $\phi = \tan^{-1} \dfrac{S_x}{S_y} $